# DCT with Matlab

Tags: matlab, dct

I tried to create a Matlab/Octave code to implement [this DCT formula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS8N8cFVd-E&t=75s).

Is the code below correct? As a help I used [the code from this site and modified it a bit](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/data-compression/lossy/jpeg/dct.htm)

```
clc
clear
close all
N=8;
Pixel=imread('small.png');
figure
imshow(Pixel)
Cosines=zeros(N,N);
for x1=1:1:N
  for i1=1:1:N
      Cosines(x1,i1)=cos( ( 2*pi*x1*(i1+0.5) )/ (2*N) );
   endfor
endfor
Coeffi=zeros(N,1)+sqrt(2);
Coeffi(1)=1;
Coefficient=zeros(N,N);
for x=1:1:N
    for y=1:1:N
      Coefficient(x,y)=Coeffi(x)*Coeffi(y);
    endfor
endfor
for i=1:1:N
    for j=1:1:N
        temp = 0.0;
        for x=1:1:N
            for y=1:1:N 
                temp = temp+(Cosines(x,i)*Cosines(y,j)*Pixel(x,y));
            endfor
        endfor
        temp = (1/N) * Coefficient(i,j);
        DCT(i,j) = temp;
    endfor
endfor
figure
imshow(DCT);
```

Comment: Have you compared the results to a known good implementation? Matlab certainly has DCT functions.

Comment: I was wondering too: any reasons you haven't used the [`dct2`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dct2.html) function? Otherwise: you can get rid of all the loops in your script by using matrices-vector products. This is not only easier to read but also much faster.

Comment: The reasons why I don't use the DCT function are: 
- I have only Octave, not Matlab (Octave has no DCT functions
- This is for learning purpose. I need to understand the implementation, not just use it.

Comment: @Florian How would you write it using matrices-vector products? I tried this [https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4ksa1wj9boo3ln/dctcode.m?dl=0], what do you think about it?

Comment: Moi, are you using latest version of Signal package https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/index.html ? Signal package lists DCT and DCT2 : https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/dct.html , https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/dct2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking how to do this without loops, here is what I would do:

```
N = 8;
n = (0:N-1);
q = (0:N-1);
C0 = cos(pi*(2*n'+1)*q/2/N);                 % unscaled DCT matrix
C = C0 * sqrt(diag([1, 2*ones(1,N-1)])/N);   % column scaling

% let's try if that is consistent with the regular DCT
v = rand(N,1);
disp(norm(C*v - dct(v,'type',3))); % it's actually a "type 3", there are many DCTs

% now a 2-D DCT looks like this
Image = rand(N,N);
Image_DCT = C*Image*C';
```

The code uses the fact that the product of a column vector (`n'`) and a row vector (`q`) gives a rank one matrix of all pairwise products. This should work even in old versions of Matlab or Octave that have no broadcasting functionality yet. Give it a try.

Not sure this is exactly the DCT you need as there are [several versions](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dct.html) of it. But you should be able to get them with some minor tweaks.

***edit**: here is the version for a type-2 DCT

```
N = 8;
n = (0:N-1);
q = (0:N-1);
C0 = cos(pi*q'*(2*n+1)/2/N);                 % unscaled DCT matrix
C = sqrt(diag([1, 2*ones(1,N-1)])/N) * C0;   % row scaling

% let's try if that is consistent with the regular DCT
v = rand(N,1);
disp(norm(C*v - dct(v,'type',2))); % it's actually a "type 2", there are many DCTs

% now a 2-D DCT looks like this
Image = rand(N,N);
Image_DCT = C*Image*C';
```

***edit2**: As you asked about the mathematics, if we consider the 2-D DCT as a matrix-matrix product in the form $D = C\cdot I\cdot C^T$ then its $(p,q)$ element is given by $$D_{p,q} = \sum_m \sum_n C_{p,m} I_{m,n} C_{q,n}.$$ Since each of the $C_{i,j}$ represents one of the cosine functions, this should explain how this computation aligns with the scalar representation you saw in the video.

Comment: Thank you, @Florian. I compared your code with the dctmtx() function. Your code produces a transformation matrix (C) which is the transpose of what dctmtx() produces.

Comment: Yeah, if you need the transpose (`dct` calls it 'Type 2') you can just transpose `C`. Alternatively, exchange `n'` and `q` to `n` and `q'`, respectively (and change column to row scaling by pre- instead of postmultiplying with the `sqrt(diag(...))` matrix).

Comment: But if I exchange n' and q to n and q', then C0 becomes a 1-by-1-matrix.

Comment: Well yeah, you need to exchange the order too. I edited the reply.

Comment: Ok thanks. 

Can somebody explain me why for example in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS8N8cFVd-E) there is cos() times cos() although in Florian's code there is C*Image*C' so cos is not multiplied with cos but with the pixels of the image. So it's not C*C' but there's A between the cosines.

Comment: I made another edit to expand `C*Image*C'` into a scalar sum representation. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: why in your code the scaling matrix is such that first row elements are multiplied wih same value although in the video and for example [in this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node231.html) there seems to be 3 different scaling values: one for k=0 ,l=0, one for k=0, l>0 and one for k>0, l>0?

Comment: Depends on which type of DCT you're after. I've used [1] which defines four different types and provided examples for Type 2 and Type 3. You can easily tweak it into other types as well though. It's either row scaling or column scaling or both. [1] https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dct.html#bvk_spb

Comment: Yes your link seems to line up with your code...

Comment: Except that they use $2n-1$ and $k-1$. Why they subtract 1?

Comment: Their sum over $n$ goes from 1 to $N$, while I was using index vectors from 0 to $N-1$. That's the reason.

Comment: But they subtract 2 from $2n+1$ and 1 from $k$.

Comment: Sure, my $n$ is their $n$ minus one, so $2n+1 \rightarrow 2(n-1)+1 = 2n-2+1 = 2n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your code also in Octave (v. 4.0 and above) by first installing two packages for Octave;
Signal - https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/index.html
Control - https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/index.html

[DCT](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/dct.html) and [DCT2](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/dct2.html) functions are parts of Signal.

Package installation instructions can be found from [here](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html).

Comment: Thank you, @Juha P. I got it installed.